# Analysis of convergence of two series, when the sum of the two series converges.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ where $\sum x_n$ and $\sum (x_n + y_n)$ both converge but $\sum y_n$ diverges.

My instinct tells me this is not possible, and I'm basing that on the Algebraic limit theorem. I should use the Cauchy Criterion to show this, i.e.
If $\sum x_n$ then given $\epsilon > 0$ $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that whenever $n>m\geq N$, it follows that $|x_{m+1} + x_{m+2} + ... + x_n| < \epsilon$

It seems I could say the same thing about $\sum (x_n + y_n)$, since the problem states that this converges as well: Given an $\epsilon > 0$ $ \exists N \in \mathbb{N} $ so that whenever $n>m\geq N$, it follows that $|(x_{m+1} + y_{m+1} + (x_{m+2} + y_{m+2}) +...+(x_n + y_n)| < \epsilon$

With that in mind, I don't see how $\sum y_n$ can diverge.
Am I on the right track? 
Thanks!!

Comment: I would suggest using the definition of convergence, unless you already have a proof that if $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge, so do $\sum(a_n+b_n)$.  In that case the proof is one line.

Comment: Write $y_n=x_n+y_n-x_n$. Then this reduces to the statement that if $\sum_i a_i$ and $\sum_i b_i$ converge, $\sum_i a_i+b_i$ converges.